# C++ compiler optimization with shorthand IF

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc, compiler-construction

I have this question in mind regarding optimazation of compiler when it comes to shorthanded if/else.

I have this function:

```
double eu_distance (const coor& x, const coor& y) {

return ((y.x - x.x)*(y.x - x.x) + (y.y - x.y)*(y.y - x.y));
}
```

I am wondering what is more efficient?

```
min = min > eucl_distance(point_a, point_b) ? eucl_distance(point_a, point_b) : min;
```

or

```
double dis = eucl_distance(point_a, point_b);
if (min > dis)
    min = dis;
```

in the former case, does compiler (in my case, GCC 4.6.2) know how to optimize that if/else to keep the return value of eucl_distance() to reuse instead of computing it twice?

A piggy back question would be:

What is more efficient?

```
(y.x - x.x)*(y.x - x.x)
```

or

```
pow((y.x - x.x),2)
```

PS: Sorry that I cannot pick more than one correct answers!! :( Thank you all for your answers! I really appreciate them!!

Comment: Profile!Profile!Profile!Profile!Profile!Profile! is the only answer.

Comment: I added gcc as a tag because the answer is likely to be quite compiler specific.

Comment: You could always compile the code and compare the assemblies by hand if in doubt. Even if you don't know assembly, if the code is the same then you know it optimizes to the same thing. Remember, though, premature optimization is the root of all evil. Generally optimizations of that sort really don't help you at all, unless you've already traced the program and found the hot path (and there isn't a more appropriate algorithm).

Comment: Look at the compiled output, or time/profile a loop of millions of itterations. it will be very compiler specific.

Comment: In theory they are the same thing, however pow() would be slower only because when the function is called it need to be put on the stack and create copies of the data you have passed it. That being said the difference in speed would be so tiny it would be better just to use pow since then you wont have type x*x*x*x*x when you get to higher powers.

Comment: The most efficient thing would probably be to use std::min, that's what I would do in this case.

Comment: Myself, I'd write `min = std::min(min, distance(a,b))` - it guarantees only one call to `distance` without needing to faff around with temporary variables, and says exactly what it's doing. And `pow` is almost certainly slower than multiplication - but there's only one way to know for sure.

Comment: @ChrisCondy There is no guarantee that `pow((y.x - x.x), 2)` generate the same results as `(y.x - x.x) * (y.x - x.x)` (although they should be close).  There's no requirement that `pow` have an overload or special handling for integral values, so even `pow(x, 2)` could be the result of evaluating a series---a different algorithm.  While I would consider any difference the mark of a poor implementation, a difference of one or two LSB wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: The compiler will most-likely inline calls to `pow` anyway (same for any standard math function that has a simple implementation). Same for `eu_distance` as long as the compiler can see the definition at the call site. If it can't, it will only cache the result if the function prototype has an `__attribute__((pure))` annotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no universal answer: you'll have to profile the code generated
by your implementation to know for sure.  In most cases, however, if
`eu_distance` is in a separate translation unit, and is not specially
annotated, the compiler will be unable to know that calling it twice
with the same arguments will give the same results; in this case, the
second form will almost surely be faster.  On the other hand, If
`eu_distance` can be inlined, any decent optimizer will end up 
generating almost exactly the same code for both.

In practice, I would almost certainly use a third form:

```
min = std::min( eu_distance( point_a, point_b ), min );
```

(I am supposing that `eucl_distance` is a typo for `eu_distance`.)

Also, I'd avoid a name like `min`.  Somebody's too likely to add a
`using namespace std;` later, or even to include `<windows.h>`, without
hvaing defined `NOMINMAX`.  (`<windows.h>` defines `min` and `max` as
macros if `NOMINMAX` has not been defined.  Which leads to some
interesting error messages if you define your own `min` or `max`.  Or
even include `<algorithm>`.)

Concerning `pow( x, 2 )`: again, you'll really have to measure, but
typically, `x * x` will be faster, even if `x` is a complicated
expression.  (Of course, if the expression is non trivial, then
recognizing that both `x` are identical may not be that easy, which
makes the code harder to read.  In such cases, you might want to
consider a small function, say `squared`, which does nothing but return
`x * x`.  Inline it if it makes a difference in performance.)

Answer (score 2):

All questions on how optimizers treat code are *hard* in the sense that there are many variables that can affect the optimizer. The first part of the answer is that caching the result of the function and reusing it will not be worse than the alternative in any circumstance, so I would go ahead and use the second approach.

As of what can be optimized in the first approach, it depends on how the code is laid out. If the compiler has access to the definition of `euclid_distance` and it can *inline* it, then it can effectively determine that the function is *pure* and will produce the same output in the second call, so it could potentially cache the value of the first call. If the compiler does not have access to the definition of the function, then it cannot know whether the first and second calls to the function will yield the same result (consider `rand()`, each call will yield a different number), so it will call the function twice. You can help there by *tagging* the function with hints for the compiler. You can google for the `__pure` attribute in gcc, which if I recall correctly it will help the optimizer in this case.

On the use of `pow` vs. plain multiplication, again, for a power of two I would just use the direct multiplication. It is basically impossible for `pow` to make it more efficiently. In this case, you need not cache `y.x-x.x` as the compiler *sees* that it is reused and can do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in theory this:

```
double dis = eucl_distance(point_a, point_b);
if (min > dis)
    min = dis;
```

is more efficient that this:

```
min = min > eucl_distance(point_a, point_b) ? eucl_distance(point_a, point_b) : min;
```

... just because you eliminate an additional call `eucl_distance(point_a, point_b)`.

But if you mark your function as "pure" or if compiler can see the definition and decide that it is pure, it will eliminate an extra call to it just like it eliminates duplicate mathematical expressions, and then generate code will be nearly the same. However, you cannot always go and check assembly etc., so I'd stick with the first case, which is cleaner.

As for your piggyback question, `(y.x - x.x)*(y.x - x.x)` is faster (you can be more specific and store result of `y - x` in tmp variable)... However, compiler is well aware of `pow` function and since second argument is compile-time expression, it can easily unroll that code to match your manually coded multiplication. But again, you cannot really rely on you, so if you can keep the code cleaner and more obvious - do it. I don't see any reason why you would want to call `pow(something, 2)` for example.

And always remember that premature optimization is no good. But still, don't write crappy slow code in the first place as well :)

Answer (score 0):

i would say:

- don't assume any compiler behaviour.
- reuse result to avoid    unecessary call

nothing tells the compiler your eucl_distance function is totally idempotent.so there quite no chance it skips the extra call assuming cached result.
 (what if you increase a static counter variable in your call???)

for the multiplication vs pow thing, my guess is it depends on the underlying processor math optimization.